# How to find missing numbers in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to find all the numbers not given in the parameter. This is what I am doing but it is not working.

```
def thing(text,text2):
  coo = [text]
  for i in string: 
      coo= i
  return coo
```

Comment: what's in `string`?

Comment: What python is this? I got `NameError: name 'string' is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

What am I doing wrong here?
You should append found letter to list, not overwrite whole list with that letter:

```
import string
def thing(text):
  coo = []
  for i in string.ascii_lowercase: 
    if i not in text:
      coo.append(i)
  return coo
```

Note also that this might be expressed in more concise way using list comprehension, that is:

```
import string
def thing(text):
    return [i for i in string.ascii_lowercase if i not in text]
```

Answer (score 1):

you are overwriting the variable `coo` with `i[0]` every time there is a match, which results in it only storing the last matching result.

try `coo.append(i[0])`